# If I use a method code to import something, such as a JOptionPane, and then call the method somewhere else, must I import it again there?

Tags: java, methods, import

I am creating a method source program, to shorten things such as JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog. I am trying to understand if in a program I write using these methods, will I need to import the JOptionPane again?

Comment: By program, I am assuming you mean across multiple classes? You would need to import it at each class provided you use this at each class.

Comment: An import is applicable per source file. If the code using these methods does not reference those imported classes directly, then you wouldn't need to import them again.

Comment: Yes, across multiple classes.

Comment: This process is known as qualification. Per source file you must define *which* class you mean when you say `JOptionPane`, by using an `import` statement. Alternatively, you can fully qualify the name inline, e.g. `javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...)`.